# Empty state in own reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I need to solve the following problem:
User change select input -> ajax request to server -> response is array of objects like {type: "img", name: "background", etc} -> depending on this response I need to create array of fields with different components(depending on type). I try to write own reducer to change state of form, but in my reducer state is always empty(

index.js

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  landing: reducers,
  form: formReducer
})

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  {},
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)

const form = document.getElementById('form')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <EditForm landing={landing} />
  </Provider>,
  form
)
```

EditForm.js

```
import * as formActions from './actions'

class EditForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    let { landing, initializeLanding } = this.props
    initializeLanding(landing)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleTemplateSelect = this.handleTemplateSelect.bind(this)
  }
  handleTemplateSelect(e) {
    this.props.actions.getVars(e.target.value)
  }
  handleSubmit(values) {
   ...
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <LandingForm
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        handleTemplateSelect={this.handleTemplateSelect}
      />
    )
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    initializeLanding: function(form) {
      dispatch(initialize('adminLandingForm', form))
    },

    actions: bindActionCreators(formActions, dispatch)
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state.form.adminLandingForm
}

EditForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'adminLandingForm'
})(EditForm)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditForm)
```

actions.js

```
const SET_VARS = 'admin-landing-from/SET_VARS'
export const getTracks = template => dispatch => {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(json => {
      dispatch({ type: SET_VARS, vars: json.data })
    })
}
```

reducers.js

```
const SET_VARS = 'admin-landing-from/SET_VARS'
const reducers = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VARS:
    console.log(state) --> Always empty
      return {
        vars: action.vars
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const reducers = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VARS:
    console.log(state) --> Always empty
      return {
        ...state,
        vars: action.vars
      }
    default:
      return state
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried, but the result is the same, here is the diff from the redux devotools to the triggering of this action:
{ reducers: 
vars[
  {
    "type": "img",
    "name": "cover"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "name": "legend"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem is you defined 2 times const SET_VARS . Just try defined only 1 time in **Reducer**, then import **SET_VARS**  into your **Action**.

Because your **state default = {}** => always you got empty object:)

Comment: I do it, but all the same